# Calling GET API in java using bearer token

Tags: java, rest, web-services, get, bearer-token

I need to send bearer token for the below code. Below code is working but I have to call another rest end point with GET which is protected by token. What addition I need to do in below code? I just want to replace url and need to add bearer token.

```
package com.shruti.getapi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class NetClientGet {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Inside the main function");
             URL weburl=new URL("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
             HttpURLConnection conn 
             = (HttpURLConnection) weburl.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
             //HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) weburl.openConnection();
             conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
             System.out.println("Output is: "+conn.getResponseCode());
             System.out.println("Output is: ");
             System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", null);
             //conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
             if(conn.getResponseCode()!=200)
             {
                 System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
                 throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error Code: "+conn.getResponseCode());
             }
             System.out.println("After the 2 call ");
             InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(in);
             String output;
             while((output=br.readLine())!=null)
             {
                 System.out.println(output);
             }
             conn.disconnect();
             
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

You want this idea, but for the [Authorization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header.

```
Authorization = credentials
```

[RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) includes an ABNF description of the credentials for an OAuth2 Bearer Token

```
 b64token    = 1*( ALPHA / DIGIT /
                   "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "+" / "/" ) *"="
 credentials = "Bearer" 1*SP b64token
```